# Is there any way to execute custom makemessages command by running "django-admin makemessages -l ja"?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, makemessages

I'm using Django1.11.5 and I created makemessages.py file in "my-app/management/commands/" directory to customise makemessages command.

And I made it to execute this command by running "python ../manage.py makemessages" from my-app directory.

But I want to execute by "django-admin makemessages -l ja".
(Running "django-admin makemessages -l ja" just executes default makemessages command)

Is there any way to execute this customised command by running "django-admin makemessages -l ja"?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should work if you did all right. Take a look at this docs part:

> In addition, manage.py is automatically created in each Django
> project. manage.py does the same thing as django-admin but takes care
> of a few things for you:
>
> - It puts your project’s package on sys.path.
> - It sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable so that it points to your
>   project’s settings.py file.

Carefully check this two moments. Since your `manage.py` works as expected, you already added your app in `INSTALLED_APPS` (after that Django can find and override default management command).